# Cordova 3.0.0 with dojo toolkit 1.9 return "unknown chromium error: -6" on android 4.2.2

Tags: cordova, dojo

I am having "unknown chromium error: -6" for a very simple Cordova/Dojo application. It did not happen with Cordova 2.9.0? Do anyone has this problem? If I run the same index.html on a desktop, the console throw this error

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. dojo.js.uncompressed.js:308
req.getText dojo.js.uncompressed.js:308
injectModule dojo.js.uncompressed.js:1522
doRequire dojo.js.uncompressed.js:6703
dojo.require dojo.js.uncompressed.js:6740
(anonymous function) index.html:63

Does anyone encounter this problem?

My application looks like this

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/dojo-1.9.1/dojox/mobile/themes/android/android.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dojo-1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true">

        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <!-- ACCIDENT TOOLKIT PAGE -->
<div dojoType="dojox.mobile.View" id="accHelp" selected="true">
    <h1 dojoType="dojox.mobile.Heading">Accident</h1>
    <div class="text">If you are in an accident, you should first move to a safe 
    location. Below are some additional actions you can take:</div>
    <ul dojoType="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">
        <li dojoType="dojox.mobile.ListItem" 
            onclick="window.location='geo:0,0?q=police';">Call the Police</li>
        <li dojoType="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
            onclick="window.location='geo:0,0?q=towing';">Call for a Tow Truck</li>
        <li dojoType="dojox.mobile.ListItem" moveTo="accInfo" transition="slide"
            onClick="itemClicked();">Exchange Driver Info</li>
        <li dojoType="dojox.mobile.ListItem" moveTo="accInfo" transition="slide"
            onClick="itemClicked();">Record Accident Location</li>
        <li dojoType="dojox.mobile.ListItem" moveTo="accInfo" transition="slide"
            onClick="itemClicked();">Take Photos of Accident</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- EXCHANGE DRIVER INFO PAGE -->
<div dojoType="dojox.mobile.View" id="accInfo">
    <h1 dojoType="dojox.mobile.Heading" back="Accident" moveTo="accHelp"
        onClick="console.log('Going back');">Driver</h1>
    <h2 dojoType="dojox.mobile.RoundRectCategory">Other Driver Info</h2>
</div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.require("dojox.mobile.parser");
            dojo.require("dojox.mobile");
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
            function itemClicked() {
                 console.log("itemClicked()");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the brand new released Cordova 3.1? With a bit of luck this might fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After days of debugging, I have finally found the problem, it is due to some of dojo javascript file name starts with underscore _ . Apparently it is a known problem in Android webkit where it refuses to load any filename starts with a underscore from the local file system.

The workaround is to use dojo build.